# Power BI "CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZE(" grouping my data in dates.. showing dates with no values as zero rather than omitting them

Tags: powerbi, dax

**I have 2 data sets:**

**1- "dateTbl" Date Table showing only first days of the week:**

[image: 1- "dateTbl" Date Table showing only first days of the week]

**2- "mainTbl" maint Table with actual data:**
[image: 2- "mainTbl" maint Table with actual data]

I used the following formula as a means to combine them:

```
weeklyGR_Tbl =
CALCULATETABLE (
    SUMMARIZE (
        mainTbl,
        dateWeeklyTbl[Date],
        "PR Count",
            CALCULATE (
                COUNT ( mainTbl[PR Status] ) + 0,
                mainTbl[PR Status] = "Closed"
                    || mainTbl[PR Status] = "Recieved"
            ),
        "PO Count",
            CALCULATE (
                COUNT ( mainTbl[PO Status] ) + 0,
                UPPER ( mainTbl[PO Status] ) = "CLOSED"
            ),
        "PO Cost",
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( mainTbl[Value] ) + 0, mainTbl[PO Status] = "Closed" )
    ),
    dateWeeklyTbl[Date] >= DATEVALUE ( "1/1/2021" ),
    FILTER ( dateWeeklyTbl, dateWeeklyTbl[Date] <= MAX ( mainTbl[Week] ) )
)
```

resulting in this Table:

[image: 3- Resulted Table]

as it is shown in the last table the first 3 days of January is not generated since it has no data in **mainTbl**.

what Im trying to do is show values there but as zeroes instead of removing those dates all together without changing the table in the formula from **mainTbl** to **dateTbl**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to summarize a table and have it return data that doesn't exist in that table. If you want those rows, you have to summarize a table that actually contains them since you can't expect them to appear from nothing.

---

As a side, note you may prefer to use [SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-summarizecolumns/) instead of SUMMARIZE along these lines

```
weeklyGR_Tbl =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    dateWeeklyTbl[Date],
    FILTER (
        dateWeeklyTbl,
        dateWeeklyTbl[Date] <= MAX ( mainTbl[Week] )
            && dateWeeklyTbl[Date] >= DATEVALUE ( "1/1/2021" )
    ),
    "PR Count",
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( mainTbl[PR Status] ) + 0,
            mainTbl[PR Status] = "Closed"
                || mainTbl[PR Status] = "Recieved"
        ),
    "PO Count",
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( mainTbl[PO Status] ) + 0,
            UPPER ( mainTbl[PO Status] ) = "CLOSED"
        ),
    "PO Cost",
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( mainTbl[Value] ) + 0, mainTbl[PO Status] = "Closed" )
)
```

Comment: i'll give that a try and get back to you